# How to include dotted words in Elasticsearch analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am using this analyzer

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "char_filter": {
            "my_char_filter": {
                "type": "mapping",
                "mappings": [
                    "- => _",
                ]
            },
            "quote_filter": {
                "type": "mapping",
                "mappings": [
                    "\\u0091=>\\u0020",
                    "\\u0092=>\\u0020",
                ]
            }
        },
        "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "char_filter": [
                    "my_char_filter", "quote_filter"
                ],
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase",
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

within this mapping:

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "fielddata": True
        },
    }
}
```

and everything works with simple keywords.

So, if I use this query

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "bool":
        {
            "must":
            [
                {
                    "query_string":
                    {
                        "query": "\".net\" OR \".com\"",
                        "fields":
                        [
                            "title",
                            "description"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "highlight":
    {
        "pre_tags":
        [
            "<match>"
        ],
        "post_tags":
        [
            "</match>"
        ],
        "fields":
        {
            "title":
            {
                "type": "fvh",
                "number_of_fragments": 0
            },
            "description":
            {
                "type": "fvh",
                "number_of_fragments": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to search ".com" in following description "*Google.com is an American multinational technology company (COM) that focuses on artificial intelligence, search engine technology, online advertising, cloud computing and computer software*" it only matches "COM" (inside parentheses) instead of ".com".

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT:**
I am finding that query:

```
"query_string" : {
    "query" : ".com OR .net OR Engine OR American" # by removing '\"'
    "fields": ["title","description"],
}
```

work partially, since it maches "Engine" and "American" but I can't know if matches "*.com" or "*.net" (a human eye would obviously be able to) because query response give me:

```
matched_keywords: {'Engine', 'American', 'Google.com'}
```

So, how can have something like

```
matched_keywords: {'Engine', 'American', '*.com'}
```

?

Comment: Are you still facing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the closest token you have is "google.com", in your case the [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) could solve it but you would lose performance.

```
{
          "wildcard": {
            "description": {
              "value": "*.com"
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to use wildcard because I'm also using exact words such as google, yahoo etc. My query should be like ' ".com" OR "Google" OR "Engine" ', but .com in this query doesn't work as it should.

Comment: I updated my answer with a consideration

Comment: Your analyzer is removing the ".". Run GET index_name/_analyzer to see. The generated token is "google.com" so it doesn't just work with ".com".